# Snake head goes out of bounds

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a snake game based on created with JavaScript and canvas.

The problem is the collision works in blocks but it works only when the head has moved to the outermost cell. How this can be solved so that this block of the head does not fall into the frame?
I tried to create an empty block of a new head, but it did not work.

```js
const playground = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = playground.getContext('2d');
const scoreBox = document.querySelector('#scoreBox');
document.addEventListener("keydown", moveSnake);

playground.width = 500;
playground.height = 500;

const gridSize = 20;
const snakeColor = "darkslategray";
const foodColor = "indianred";
const spaceGrid = 2;

let tileCount = playground.width / gridSize;
let snakeVelocityX = 0;
let snakeVelocityY = 0;
let start = true;
let canDeath = false;
let drawSnakeTail = true;
const SnakeLen = [];

const gameFruits = [];
let snakeTail = 3;

function sleep(ms) {
  ms += new Date().getTime();
  while (new Date() < ms) {}
}

function getRandCoord() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * tileCount);
}

let snakeX = playground.width / 2 - gridSize / 2;
let snakeY = playground.height / 2 - gridSize / 2;
console.log(snakeX);

function drawGameScene() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "snow";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, playground.width, playground.height);
}

function moveSnake(ev) {
  const oldSnakeSpeedX = snakeVelocityX;
  const oldSnakeSpeedY = snakeVelocityY;

  switch (ev.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      snakeVelocityX = -1;
      snakeVelocityY = 0;
      break;
    case 38:
      snakeVelocityX = 0;
      snakeVelocityY = -1;
      break;
    case 39:
      snakeVelocityX = 1;
      snakeVelocityY = 0;
      break;
    case 40:
      snakeVelocityX = 0;
      snakeVelocityY = 1;
      break;

  }
  canDeath = true;
  if ((snakeVelocityX !== 0 && oldSnakeSpeedX !== 0 && snakeVelocityX !== oldSnakeSpeedX) ||
    (snakeVelocityY !== 0 && oldSnakeSpeedY !== 0 && snakeVelocityY !== oldSnakeSpeedY)) {
    snakeVelocityX = oldSnakeSpeedX;
    snakeVelocityY = oldSnakeSpeedY;
  }
}

function drawFruits() {
  for (let i = 0; i < gameFruits.length; i++) {
    const fruit = gameFruits[i];

    ctx.fillStyle = fruit.color;
    ctx.fillRect(fruit.x * gridSize, fruit.y * gridSize, gridSize - 2, gridSize - 2);
  }
}

function SnakeCollisionFoodHandler() {
  for (let i = 0; i < gameFruits.length; i++) {
    const fruit = gameFruits[i];

    if (snakeX === fruit.x && snakeY === fruit.y) {
      snakeTail += fruit.points;

      gameFruits.splice(i, 1);

      spawnFruitTile();

    }
  }
}

function containsObject(obj, list) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i]["x"] == obj["x"] || list[i]["y"] == obj["y"]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function spawnFruitTile() {
  let x = getRandCoord();
  y = getRandCoord();
  coors = {
    x,
    y
  };
  if (containsObject(coors, SnakeLen)) {
    if (x === gridSize + 4 || y === gridSize + 4 || x === 0 || y === 0) {
      spawnFruitTile();
    } else {
      gameFruits.push({
        x: x,
        y: y,
        points: 1,
        color: foodColor
      });
    }

  } else {
    spawnFruitTile();
  }

}

function onGameOver() {
  drawSnakeTail = false;
  death_score = snakeTail - 3;
  ctx.font = "20px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = '#20201d';
  window.pauseAll = true;
  ctx.fillText("Game over\nScore:" + death_score, (playground.width - 200) / 2, playground.height / 2);
  // alert();
  // location.reload();
}

function drawSnake() {
  console.log(SnakeLen);
  if (drawSnakeTail == true) {
    if (start == true) {
      snakeVelocityY = 1;
      snakeVelocityX = 1;
    }
    snakeX += snakeVelocityX;
    snakeY += snakeVelocityY;
    if (snakeX < 0) {
      snakeX = tileCount - 1;
    }
    if (snakeX > tileCount - 1) {
      snakeX = 0;
    }
    if (snakeY < 0) {
      snakeY = tileCount - 1;
    }
    if (snakeY > tileCount - 1) {
      snakeY = 0;
    }
    drawGameScene();

    ctx.fillStyle = snakeColor;

    for (let i = 0; i < SnakeLen.length; i++) {
      const {
        x,
        y
      } = SnakeLen[i];
      ctx.fillRect(x * gridSize, y * gridSize, gridSize - spaceGrid, gridSize - spaceGrid);
      if (start == true) {
        snakeVelocityY = 0;
        snakeVelocityX = 0;
        setTimeout(start = false, 100);
      }
      if (start == false) {
        if (canDeath == true) {
          if ((x === snakeX && y === snakeY) && (snakeX !== 0 || snakeY !== 0)) {
            ctx.fillRect(x * gridSize, y * gridSize, gridSize - spaceGrid, gridSize - spaceGrid);
            setTimeout(onGameOver, 100);
          }
        } //playground.width
        // console.log(snakeX , playground.width - tileCount, gridSize + spaceGrid, x);
        if (snakeX === gridSize + 4 || snakeY === gridSize + 4 || snakeX === 0 || snakeY === 0) { //
          ctx.fillRect(x * gridSize, y * gridSize, gridSize - spaceGrid, gridSize - spaceGrid);
          setTimeout(onGameOver, 100);
        }

      }

    }
  }

  SnakeLen.push({
    x: snakeX,
    y: snakeY
  });


  while (SnakeLen.length > snakeTail) {
    SnakeLen.shift();
  }
}

function drawBorder() {
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  ctx.lineWidth = 40;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#076826";
  ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, playground.width, playground.height);
}

function drawScore() {
  ctx.font = "20px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = '#20201d';
  ctx.fillText("Score:" + (snakeTail - 3), 10, 20);
}

function onGameFrame() {
  drawSnake();
  drawFruits();
  SnakeCollisionFoodHandler();
  drawBorder();
  drawScore();
}

(function onGameInit() {
  spawnFruitTile();
  setInterval(onGameFrame, 100);
}());
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 0.5px solid black;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <canvas width="500px" height="500px"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you won't set a timeout around the `onGameOver` call, the game will end in the current position. I guess this happens because javascript is able to run another cycle so another frame is drawn before the event runs:

```js
if (snakeX === gridSize + 4 || snakeY === gridSize + 4 || snakeX === 0 || snakeY === 0) { //
  ctx.fillRect(x * gridSize, y * gridSize, gridSize - spaceGrid, gridSize - spaceGrid);
  onGameOver(); // <-- removed the setTimeout wrap
}
```

```js
const playground = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = playground.getContext('2d');
const scoreBox = document.querySelector('#scoreBox');
document.addEventListener("keydown", moveSnake);

playground.width = 500;
playground.height = 500;

const gridSize = 20;
const snakeColor = "darkslategray";
const foodColor = "indianred";
const spaceGrid = 2;

let tileCount = playground.width / gridSize;
let snakeVelocityX = 0;
let snakeVelocityY = 0;
let start = true;
let canDeath = false;
let drawSnakeTail = true;
const SnakeLen = [];

const gameFruits = [];
let snakeTail = 3;

function sleep(ms) {
  ms += new Date().getTime();
  while (new Date() < ms) {}
}

function getRandCoord() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * tileCount);
}

let snakeX = playground.width / 2 - gridSize / 2;
let snakeY = playground.height / 2 - gridSize / 2;
console.log(snakeX);

function drawGameScene() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "snow";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, playground.width, playground.height);
}

function moveSnake(ev) {
  const oldSnakeSpeedX = snakeVelocityX;
  const oldSnakeSpeedY = snakeVelocityY;

  switch (ev.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      snakeVelocityX = -1;
      snakeVelocityY = 0;
      break;
    case 38:
      snakeVelocityX = 0;
      snakeVelocityY = -1;
      break;
    case 39:
      snakeVelocityX = 1;
      snakeVelocityY = 0;
      break;
    case 40:
      snakeVelocityX = 0;
      snakeVelocityY = 1;
      break;

  }
  canDeath = true;
  if ((snakeVelocityX !== 0 && oldSnakeSpeedX !== 0 && snakeVelocityX !== oldSnakeSpeedX) ||
    (snakeVelocityY !== 0 && oldSnakeSpeedY !== 0 && snakeVelocityY !== oldSnakeSpeedY)) {
    snakeVelocityX = oldSnakeSpeedX;
    snakeVelocityY = oldSnakeSpeedY;
  }
}

function drawFruits() {
  for (let i = 0; i < gameFruits.length; i++) {
    const fruit = gameFruits[i];

    ctx.fillStyle = fruit.color;
    ctx.fillRect(fruit.x * gridSize, fruit.y * gridSize, gridSize - 2, gridSize - 2);
  }
}

function SnakeCollisionFoodHandler() {
  for (let i = 0; i < gameFruits.length; i++) {
    const fruit = gameFruits[i];

    if (snakeX === fruit.x && snakeY === fruit.y) {
      snakeTail += fruit.points;

      gameFruits.splice(i, 1);

      spawnFruitTile();

    }
  }
}

function containsObject(obj, list) {
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i]["x"] == obj["x"] || list[i]["y"] == obj["y"]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

function spawnFruitTile() {
  let x = getRandCoord();
  y = getRandCoord();
  coors = {
    x,
    y
  };
  if (containsObject(coors, SnakeLen)) {
    if (x === gridSize + 4 || y === gridSize + 4 || x === 0 || y === 0) {
      spawnFruitTile();
    } else {
      gameFruits.push({
        x: x,
        y: y,
        points: 1,
        color: foodColor
      });
    }

  } else {
    spawnFruitTile();
  }

}

function onGameOver() {
  drawSnakeTail = false;
  death_score = snakeTail - 3;
  ctx.font = "20px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = '#20201d';
  window.pauseAll = true;
  ctx.fillText("Game over\nScore:" + death_score, (playground.width - 200) / 2, playground.height / 2);
  // alert();
  // location.reload();
}

function drawSnake() {
  console.log(SnakeLen);
  if (drawSnakeTail == true) {
    if (start == true) {
      snakeVelocityY = 1;
      snakeVelocityX = 1;
    }
    snakeX += snakeVelocityX;
    snakeY += snakeVelocityY;
    if (snakeX < 0) {
      snakeX = tileCount - 1;
    }
    if (snakeX > tileCount - 1) {
      snakeX = 0;
    }
    if (snakeY < 0) {
      snakeY = tileCount - 1;
    }
    if (snakeY > tileCount - 1) {
      snakeY = 0;
    }
    drawGameScene();

    ctx.fillStyle = snakeColor;

    for (let i = 0; i < SnakeLen.length; i++) {
      const {
        x,
        y
      } = SnakeLen[i];
      ctx.fillRect(x * gridSize, y * gridSize, gridSize - spaceGrid, gridSize - spaceGrid);
      if (start == true) {
        snakeVelocityY = 0;
        snakeVelocityX = 0;
        setTimeout(start = false, 100);
      }
      if (start == false) {
        if (canDeath == true) {
          if ((x === snakeX && y === snakeY) && (snakeX !== 0 || snakeY !== 0)) {
            ctx.fillRect(x * gridSize, y * gridSize, gridSize - spaceGrid, gridSize - spaceGrid);
            setTimeout(onGameOver, 100);
          }
        } //playground.width
        // console.log(snakeX , playground.width - tileCount, gridSize + spaceGrid, x);
        if (snakeX === gridSize + 4 || snakeY === gridSize + 4 || snakeX === 0 || snakeY === 0) { //
          ctx.fillRect(x * gridSize, y * gridSize, gridSize - spaceGrid, gridSize - spaceGrid);
          onGameOver();
        }
      }

    }
  }

  SnakeLen.push({
    x: snakeX,
    y: snakeY
  });


  while (SnakeLen.length > snakeTail) {
    SnakeLen.shift();
  }
}

function drawBorder() {
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  ctx.lineWidth = 40;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#076826";
  ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, playground.width, playground.height);
}

function drawScore() {
  ctx.font = "20px Arial";
  ctx.fillStyle = '#20201d';
  ctx.fillText("Score:" + (snakeTail - 3), 10, 20);
}

function onGameFrame() {
  drawSnake();
  drawFruits();
  SnakeCollisionFoodHandler();
  drawBorder();
  drawScore();
}

(function onGameInit() {
  spawnFruitTile();
  setInterval(onGameFrame, 100);
}());
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 0.5px solid black;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <canvas width="500px" height="500px"></canvas>
</div>
```